# How to prevent redirect to view after send json data to httppost action in mvc3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a problem when developing a single page web app.

When jQuery send json to HTTPPOST action:

```
$('#user_dialog .create').click(function () {
                            var user = getInfoUser();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "User")',
                                async: false,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                                datatype: 'json',
                                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#user_dialog').dialog("close");
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

My HTTPPOST action in controller will handle the request

```
[HttpPost]
  public String Create(UserAddViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(true);
            }
            catch
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(false);
            }
        }
```

And my jQuery *success* callback function will be fired and data 'true' will be received.

But the problem now is after this, the page will be redirect to **/User/Create** view page

I don't want it redirect to the page, i just want to handle the UI by my jQuery code.

Is that because it is HTTPPOST action?

What is the actual reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the thing you're clicking is a URL. You're not preventing the default event (loading the url) from occuring in your click event

```
$('#user_dialog .create').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //rest of function
```

Whenever a click event finishes, the default event (loading a URL if it's a link, submitting a form if it's a submit button, toggling a checkbox, etc.) will occur next. In order to prevent this you must do it explicitly either using `preventDefault()` or by returning false. See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ for the documentation.

Comment: EXACTLY !!! Sorry but what does preventDefault do? is it because it will submit the form twice ? Is it because preventDefault will block the default form submitting ?